# Laplace transform of multiplication of three terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Okay, so I have

$${f}(t)= t\mathrm{e}^{-2t}\sin 2t.$$

In order to do a Laplace transform, I'm pretty positive I cannot just split it up cause that would basically break the rules of math. I understand how to do a transform with just two, not three, t's.

Like I know that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{L}\left[t\mathrm{e}^{-2t}\right](s) &=& \frac{1}{(s+2)^2} \\ \\ \\  \\
\mathcal{L}\left[\mathrm{e}^{-2t}\sin 2t \right](s) &=& \frac{2}{(s+2)^2+4}
\end{eqnarray*}

But how do I find $\mathcal{L}\left[\mathrm{f}(t)\right](s)$?

Help!

Comment: I think you want you to use some properties of the Laplace transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! Just let me get my notation clear.

Let $\mathrm{f}$ be a suitable function, and define the Laplace Transform of $\mathrm{f}$ as $\mathrm{F}$, given by
$$\mathrm{F}(s) = \int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{f}(t)~\mathrm{e}^{-st}~\mathrm{d}t \ \ \text{where } \ \ \ s>0$$

If $\mathrm{f}(t) = \mathrm{e}^{-2t}\sin 2t$ then you have already shown that
$$\mathrm{F}(s) = \frac{2}{(s+2)^2+4}$$

There is one -- among *many* -- nice little facts about the Laplace Transform. One of them is that the Laplace Transform of $t\,\mathrm{f}(t)$ is given by the negative of the, i.e. derivative $\displaystyle{-\frac{\mathrm{dF}}{\mathrm{d}s}}$, where $\mathrm{F}$ is the Laplace Transform of $\mathrm{f}$.

In other words, the Laplace Transform of $t\,\mathrm{e}^{-2t}\sin 2t$ is given by
$$-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(\frac{2}{(s+2)^2+4}\right)$$

Can you find this derivative using, for example, the quotient rule?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the identity

> $$ \sin 2t = \frac{1}{2i}\left( e^{i2t} - e^{-i2t}\right), $$

and the linearity of Laplace transform.

**Added:** You can go this way, first you can use the Laplace transform of $\sin 2t$

> $$ F(s) = \frac{2}{s^2+4}, $$

then use the two properties

> $$ e^{at}=F(s-a), $$

and

> $$ t^nf(t) = (-1)^n F^{(n)}(s) $$

in a row.

Comment: The OP told us that s/he already knew the Laplace Transform of $\mathrm{e}^{-2t}\sin 2t$.

Comment: @FlybyNight: It is enough for him to know the Laplace transform of $\sin 2t$ then he can use some properties of the Laplace transform and I believe this is the intention behind this question.

Comment: The OP says "I know that... $\mathcal{L}(\mathrm{e}^{-2t}\sin 2t) = \ldots$" The OP then goes on to say "But how do I find $\mathcal{L}(\mathrm{f})$" They want to know how to use the knowledge of $\mathcal{L}(\mathrm{e}^{-2t}\sin 2t)$ to get to $\mathcal{L}(t\,\mathrm{e}^{-2t}\sin 2t)$.